# How to redirect WCF service calls to different operations based on the message content

Tags: c#, json, wcf, wcf-routing, idispatchmessageinspector

I have an operation (method) in a WCF service. the operation has a parameter of Json content.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string NotifyAuditLineUpdated(AuditLineUpdatedModel notification);
```

For this parameter AuditLineUpdatedModel, I have created a pre-definied class using DataContractAttributes and DataMemberAttributes to map the json message to an object during the deserialization.

However, I have a problem is that the client has **a different Json message structures** under **same field name** where I cannot combine all cases in a single class. In other words, the Json message has a field which could have **different structure (not value)**; therefore, I'm trying to **direct the call to a different operations** which could satisfy the variety of the Json message.

So far I have found that WCF provides routing on the service level. I wonder if possible to route the calls on operation level. In other words, I have a single service with two operations of different parameter types. Is it possible to catch the call and check the message content, and then direct the call to a proper operation based on the message?

For your information, I have tried **IDispatchMessageInspector** (message inspector feature) of WCF. I was able to check the message content, but I am not able to redirect or change the destination (To uri) address.
**Note:** In addition, the client service is not able to send different uri requests for the two different cases.

Comment: -"but I am not able to redirect or change the destination (To uri)" - can you tell us why? If you have another service to process the new message type, you surely should be able to create a new service client for that service and process the message using the new service and then return the result back to the original service.

Comment: Hi @KosalaW, when I try to execute the following line, I'm getting an error request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("To", "To" , <new address>)); 
Error Message: Envelope Version 'EnvelopeNone (schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none)'; does not support adding Message Headers

Comment: See my answer below. Let me know if you have further questions. you should not have to add headers for the new service. You only need the body.

Comment: Answer updated to show IDispatchMessageInspector override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example. The code is conceptual and you will have to implement it the way you want.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string NotifyAuditLineUpdated(AuditLineUpdatedModel notification);

// you can host this somewhere else
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
string MyInternalService(AuditLineUpdatedModel1 notification);

public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    object response;
    var isCallToMyInternalServiceRequired = VerificationMethod(request, out response);
    if(!isCallToMyInternalServiceRequired)
    {
        using(var client = new NotifyAuditLineUpdatedClient())
        {
            return client.NotifyAuditLineUpdated(response as AuditLineUpdatedModel);
        }
    }

    using(var client = new MyInternalServiceClient())
    {
        return client.MyInternalServiceClient(response as AuditLineUpdatedModel1);
    }
}   

private bool VerificationMethod(object notification, out object output)
{
    // your validation method.
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer I got so far, but one thing would made this answer a complete one. Using this solution, I could call any method I need here by name based on the received request, but one thing would still cause an issue is that WCF will call the original client-request method, cannot I fully deviate the call to another method here?